# angular 6 get ngmodel binding name

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-ngmodel

I'm developing custom component in angular 6, using `controlvalueaccessor`

currently my code  correctly works.
but I need to expand it by enabling it to handle shared data, my simplest solution is to use 'shared' keyword before binding name, as follow:

```
[(ngModel)]="shared.Something"
```

and behind the scene manually manage data, so I need to get the binding name to be able to handle this situation. 
(I searched and tried, but no luck)

any suggestion?

Comment: Do you set the `shared` object in your ts file?

Comment: let me explain: it's a custom checkbox, and i want to inject SharedData as a service into checkbox, not to the component that will use checkbox, and use "shared" keyword as explained above.